# Usage of the word "gelangte"

Tags: grammar-identification

> Wann und wie sie genau nach Europa **gelangte**, ist unklar, als sicher gilt jedoch, dass die ersten Kartoffeln den Weg über die kanarischen Inseln zu uns nahmen.

I checked in dictionary and there seems to be no such word as gelangt.. but there seems to be "gelang" and "gelingt" which both seems to come from "gelingen" somehow.. so where does "gelangt" come from?

Comment: https://www.dwds.de/wb/gelangen

Comment: Try Wiktionary; it usually lists all inflections of a word, not just the "dictionary form". It's very useful for learners who haven't memorized every irregular verb yet. Wouldn't it be "gelangten" though? Since "Kartoffeln" is plural.

Comment: Isn't " sie " the subject? @RDBury

Comment: Imo the close votes are unjustified. How would one find *gelangt* in a dictionary? See also @Janka's answer.

Comment: @tryst with freedom - In isolation the "sie" could be "she" or "it", but it seems obvious that it's referring to "potatoes", so it means "they" here. Also, "ersten" is plural. Everything agrees with a plural "sie" except for the verb conjugation.

Comment: @Olafant - The guidelines only ask that people "Tell us why a dictionary did not help you." And the poster did that so I think you have a point. I personally wouldn't ask unless I'd already tried several dictionaries including Wiktionary and DWDS. Also, Google Translate is available for free and has a dictionary built in; you just have to highlight the word.

Comment: @Olafant, i did not vote to close, but this is the DWDS result: "Wir haben für Ihre Abfrage nach gelangte den Artikel gelangen als am besten passend ermittelt."

Comment: @RDBury, we don't know what the preceding sentence is, but this seems to be a generic singular: "Wann und wie die Kartoffel genau nach Europa gelangte..."

Comment: @Carsten S - That seems possible, though it wouldn't work in English. You could certainly say "When the potato first arrived... ." But it sounds wrong to say "Where and it arrived in Europe, ... the first potatoes came via ... ." The pronoun "it" doesn't agree with the noun "first potatoes". Even if "it" is referring to something in a previous sentence, it would be better to make the second clause it's own sentence to avoid confusion. Perhaps pronouns work differently in German.

Comment: @RDBury, i imagined something like: "The potato is native to South America. Even and how exactly it reached Europe is unknown, but it is considered was certain that the first potatoes came to via the Canary Islands." But I about that an omitted "n" is just as likely.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are three very similar verbs. Don't confuse them.

- gelingen, es gelingt, es gelang, es ist gelungen — to succeed
- gelangen, es gelangt, es gelangte, es ist gelangt — to end up, to reach
- langen, es langt, es langte, es hat gelangt — to be sufficient

Comment: There is also the variant "anlangen" (for arrive); the adjective "lang" (which has the plural Accusative and Dative form "langen"); the verb "längen" (elongate) which has a perfect participle "gelängt". Who on Earth invented this language?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: ze Germans, obviously ;)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Don't forget that *langen* helpfully also means “to take” and “to give.”